# Best Practice to update list of enitities in DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

I'm developing Spring Boot Rest Application. ORM Hibernate. I have endpoint for update related entities in DB, for example I have table "form" and table "rows", every row attached to form, so one form can contain multiple rows in table "rows" and every row has link to "form".

Use case: we are getting list of rows to save

- some of them new so is does not contains ids
- some of them changed so is containes id and I need to update some fields
- some of them deleted (so we don't have it in list that sended from front end).

Is the best way to do it is handling all this cases manually? Or are there any ORM/Spring approach to handle this or similar situation. May be there are some best practises or approaches I should read about?

Thanks for help!

Comment: do you need to delete the records from db for those not sent in the request?

Comment: @deadshot Yes I do

Comment: [How to merge entity collections with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/) may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hibernate does support this. You can, depending upon what a Form and Row are in your model (ex. Does Row need to be a separate entity?) use one of the following:

- `@ElementCollection` with an `@Embeddable` row
- `@OneToMany` if Row itself is an entity (likely not in this case)

You will also need to consider the nature of the update: are you replacing the entire entity (such as you would for a PUT operation) or are you simply patching over the specific attributes sent? In the former case, these approaches will work much better than in the latter.

Editing my answer to provide more clarity:

The best approach would of course depend on the nuances of what you’re trying to do. Do you for example need a row to be updated or accessed outside the context of a form? Does it then need to have a separate ID and if so, what is the purpose served by having that? As far as best practices are concerned, even for the one-to-many approach explained, where you would write the annotations and how you’d use the ORM also matters, Ex: having only the Form entity own the relationship and keeping row oblivious about it means you cannot do something as simple as add a single new row to a form without reading and writing back the entirety of Form which would be wasteful and introduce potential issues with transactionality assuming default isolation levels.